# All properties aren't showing up in properties tab

Tags: properties

Only a few properties are showing up in the properties tab. I saw a similar post but didn't find a solution that worked. [image]

I've tried switching between rendered and object view, switching to modeling tab works but I want to be able to see all properties in layout. can anyone help?

Comment: Hello :). Your properties tab is pinned - the white pin in top right corner.

Comment: Thank you so much I couldn't figure this out and I'm relatively new to blender so this helps a lot.

Comment: No problem, welcome to Blender :)